# can the maximum likelihood estimator depend on the parametrization?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mathematical-statistics

That is, say I have a distribution with parameter $\theta$.

If I re-write it with a parameter $a$ such that $a^3=\theta$, is it possible
that doing maximum likelihood estimation on a will yield an estimate $\hat a$ such that
$\hat a^3 \neq \hat \theta$?

Could it be the case for another function different than $x^3$?

If so, what are some criteria to choose a parametrization?

Comment: An estimate is a realization of the estimator.Usually, the realization of an estimator does not equal the target, $\hat\theta\neq\theta$. This is because a particular property of a sample usually does not equal the corresponding property of the population. Hence, it would not at all be surprising if $(\hat{a})^3\neq\theta$ even if $(\hat{a})^3$ is an estimator targeting $\theta$. Is your question perhaps whether it is possible that $(\hat{a}^{\text{MLE}})^3\neq\hat\theta^{\text{MLE}}$?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/proof-of-invariance-property-of-mle, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438778/question-about-casella-and-bergers-proof-of-mle-invariance, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390741/invariance-property

Answer (score 8):

The Invariance Property of Maximum Likelihood Estimators (MLEs) says, if $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then for any function $\tau(\theta)$ the MLE of  $\tau(\theta)$ is  $\tau(\hat{\theta})$.

So, if you define $a^3=\theta$, once you obtained your MLE for $\theta$, $\hat{\theta}$, you can apply the inverse function by taking the cubed root of $\hat{\theta}$ and obtain the MLE of $a$ (i.e. $\hat{a}=\hat{\theta}^{1\over{3}}$)

**Update:**

I've added the proof mentioned by Thomas Lumley in the comments:

Let $\hat{\eta}$ denote the value that maximizes $L^*(\eta|\textbf{x})$.  We must show that $L^*(\hat{\eta}|\textbf{x})$=$L^*(\tau(\hat{\theta})|\textbf{x})$.  The maxima of $L$ and $L^*$ coincide, so we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
L^{*}(\hat{\eta}|\textbf{x}) & = & \underset{\eta}{\text{sup}}\underset{\{\theta:\tau(\theta)=\eta\}}{\text{sup}}\,L(\theta|\textbf{x})\\
 & = & \underset{\theta}{\text{sup}}L(\theta|\textbf{x})\\
 & = & L(\hat{\theta}|\textbf{x}),
\end{eqnarray*}

The first and third equalities hold by definition of $L^{*}$ and
$\hat{\theta}$ respectively, and the second equality holds because
the iterated maximization is equal to the unconditional maximization
over $\theta$, obtained at $\hat{\theta}$. Further,

\begin{eqnarray*}
L(\hat{\theta}|\textbf{x}) & = & \underset{\{\theta:\tau(\theta)=\tau(\hat{\theta})\}}{\text{sup}}L(\theta|\textbf{x})\\
 & = & L^{*}\left[\tau(\hat{\theta})|\textbf{x}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, the string of equalities shows that $L^{*}(\hat{\eta}|\textbf{x})=L^{*}\left[\tau(\hat{\theta})|\textbf{x}\right]$
and that $\tau(\hat{\theta})$ is the MLE of $\tau(\theta)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the equivariance property holds even if the transformation isn't invertible.

Comment: Good point, @ThomasLumley. I don't think I made that clear and, in fact, may have obfuscated that point with my example (or the OP's example).

Comment: Wow. Very cool (and a bit surprising!). No conditions on tau? Do you happen to have a good statement of the theorem

Comment: There are no conditions.  The first sentence above is a good statement.  It's exactly what you'd find in any textbook definition.

Comment: The *proof* is much more straightforward for invertible transformations.   This question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246587/does-equivariance-of-the-mle-require-the-function-be-invertible gives  a reference to the text by Casella and Berger for the  general result.

Comment: @ThomasLumley, I've added proof under the Update heading in case the OP does not have access to the book.